# Recursive sequence. Value is resetting to 0

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

> Solve
> $$\begin{cases}
> {a_n} = 5a_{n-1} - 6a_{n-2} + 6 \cdot 3^{n}\\
> {a_0} = 1, a_1=50
> \end{cases}$$

The problem I've got here is the C resetting.
It happens to me sometimes and I don't know why.
Hope someone can clear it up for me.
Thanks.

[image: My trying solution]

Comment: Your $a_n$ satisfies the recurrence only if you leave out the term $6\cdot3^n$. This is not unlike in the case of differential equations when the term leading to inhomogeneity happens to be a solution of the homogeneous DE. The remedy is the same: you need to add a term like $Cn\cdot 3^n$ into the ansatz.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen How do I know when to add n Cn⋅3n after C? How will I know when this happens? Because until now I solved like in the picture and usually got it right ..

Comment: You wrong in $a_n^p$. The $a_n^p$ should be $a_n^p=A\cdot 2^n+C\cdot n\cdot 3^n$

Comment: @OngkyDennyWijaya Can you please show me the full sultions because iam lost

Comment: @OngkyDennyWijaya How do I position so I don't get C= 0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have found the general solution of the [homogeneous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) part which is
$$a_{hom}(n)=A2^n+B3^n.$$ 
As regards the particular solution $a_{*}(n)$, you should apply the [method of undetermined coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients) in the correct way. Since $3$ is a solution of order $1$ of the characteristic polynomial, you have to try with $a_{*}(n)=Cn3^n$ (not simply $C3^n$) where $C$ is a constant to be determined: if we plug it into the recurrence we find
$$Cn3^n = 5C(n-1)3^{n-1} - 6C(n-2)3^{n-2} + 6 \cdot 3^{n}$$
that is
$$9Cn = 15C(n-1) - 6C(n-2) + 54$$
or
$$0=-15C+12C+54$$
and we have that $C=54/3=18$.

Comment: Hey Robert how are you? :) thanks! I put Cn instead of C alone and still dont see different

Comment: THANKS! Shoudl i always put an n next to the c? because i didnt do it until now and it worked fine(mostly)

Comment: Do you see the difference now?

Comment: As I told you, it depends on the fact that $3$ is a solution of the characteristic polynomial. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients#Typical_forms_of_the_particular_integral In particular the last line "If a term in the above particular integral..."

Comment: omg i understand now! so everytime one of the answers is equal to the nonhomogeneous parts of the series, I will need to add an Cn ?

Comment: Yes, multiply by $n^m$ where $m$ is the multiplicity of the root.

Comment: Gracias Robert I would have got less in my test tomorrow if you wasnt here haha

Comment: Good luck on your test!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99529/discussion-between-lorin-sherry-and-robert-z).

Answer (score 0):

$a_n-5a_{n-1}+6a_{n-2}=6\cdot 3^n$, with $a_0=1$, $a_1=50$.

First we find solution of homogenous recurrence relation

$$a_n-5a_{n-1}+6a_{n-2}=0.$$

$r^2-5r+6=0$, we have $r=2$ with multiplicity 1 and $r=3$ with multiplicity 1. So,

$$a_n^h=A\cdot 2^n+B\cdot 3^n.$$

Because in the right-hand side $$a_n-5a_{n-1}+6a_{n-2}=6\cdot 3^n,$$

Now we have $r=2$ with multiplicity 1 and $r=3$ with multiplicity 2. Let the particular solution

$$a_n^p=C\cdot 2^n+D\cdot 3^n + E\cdot n\cdot 3^n.$$

Now delete the terms which appear similar in the $a_n^h$,

$$a_n^p=E\cdot n\cdot 3^n.$$

Substituting new $a_n^p$ into $$a_n-5a_{n-1}+6a_{n-2}=6\cdot 3^n,$$

we have

\begin{eqnarray}
a_n-5a_{n-1}+6a_{n-2}&=&6\cdot 3^n\\
E\cdot n\cdot 3^n-5E\cdot (n-1)\cdot 3^{n-1}+6E\cdot (n-2)\cdot 3^{n-2}&=&6\cdot 3^n\\
E\cdot n\cdot 3^n-\dfrac{5}{3}E\cdot (n-1)\cdot 3^{n}+\dfrac{2}{3}E\cdot (n-2)\cdot 3^{n}&=&6\cdot 3^n\\
E\cdot n\cdot 3^n-\dfrac{5}{3}E\cdot n\cdot 3^{n}+\dfrac{5}{3}E\cdot 3^{n}+\dfrac{2}{3}E\cdot n\cdot 3^{n}-\dfrac{4}{3}E\cdot 3^{n}&=&6\cdot 3^n\\
\dfrac{1}{3}E\cdot 3^{n}&=&6\cdot 3^n\\
\end{eqnarray}

Now, we have $E=18$. So, the particular solution will be
$$a_n^p=18\cdot n\cdot 3^n.$$

Now,

$$a_n=a_n^h+a_n^p.$$

$$a_n=A\cdot 2^n+B\cdot 3^n+18\cdot n\cdot 3^n.$$

To find $A$ and $B$, we substitute initial value.

$$a_0=A\cdot 2^0+B\cdot 3^0+18\cdot 0\cdot 3^0=A+B=1.$$
$$a_1=A\cdot 2^1+B\cdot 3^1+18\cdot 1\cdot 3^1=2A+3B+54=50\iff 2A+3B=-4.$$

Solving last two equations, we get $A=7$ and $B=-6$. So we get the solution is

$$a_n=7\cdot 2^n-6\cdot 3^n+18\cdot n\cdot 3^n.$$